# 2.5d Map Collision with Player

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I'm planning on making a 2d Top-down rpg, so I decided to play around with some things before I get started. For an example I took [this map](http://www.spriters-resource.com/gameboy_advance/mother3/sheet/6220) from Mother 3. 
  I had originally planned to have an array of Rectangles that would be checked each time Update() was called to check whether the sprite was colliding with them, but some of the shapes are way too complicated. Is there another way I should be doing collision detection? Because this way doesn't seem feasible on a large scale.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different kinds of bounding shapes depending on the object. Simply let them all implement a common interface:

```
public interface IBoundingShape
{
    // Replace 'Rectangle' with your character bounding shape
    bool Intersects(Rectangle rect);
}
```

Then you can have a `Circle`, `Rectangle`, `Polygon` all implement `IBoundingShape`. For more complex objects you could introduce a compound bounding shape:

```
public class CompoundBoundingShape : IBoundingShape
{
    public CompoundBoundingShape()
    {
        Shapes = new List<IBoundingShape>();
    }

    public List<IBoundingShape> Shapes { get; private set; }

    public bool Interesects(Rectangle rect)
    {
        foreach (var shape in Shapes)
        {
            if (shape.Intersects(rect))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Additionally you can use the `CompoundBoundingShape` as a bounding hierarchy to early discard objects.

In game you just iterate over all game objects and check if the player bounding shape intersects with scenery.

Comment: Would it be possible to define a polygon by a set of vertices?

Comment: Sure, just design your intersection method accordingly. Search for *rectangle polygon intersection* or something similar. [Point in polygon algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) could also be of interest for you.